# Difference between PHP, Java Servlet and traditional CGI program

Tags: java, php, servlets, cgi

I learned that program that handle GET/POST request are usually CGI programs.
This definition is too board. Can anyone tell me what exactly a CGU program is? CGI programs handle GET/POST method, but Java servlets and PHP can do that too, so what is the difference between PHP and traditional CGI program; Java servlet and CGI program?

Comment: Reference:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface

Comment: Also look in the related column, there seem to be interesting things there like [How do CGIs and Servlets execute differently?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2376823)

Answer (score 4):

> I learned that program that handle GET/POST request are usually CGI programs.

No, they aren't. They used to be, but CGI is no longer the "usual" method.

> Can anyone tell me what exactly a CGI program is?

CGI is a [standard](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3875) way for a web server to run a piece of software, pass data to it (such as the URL and the body of a POST request), and then read data back from the program to use as the HTTP response.

> Java servlets and PHP can do that too

A servlet is a different way of doing the same job, but is Java specific.

PHP is a programming language. You can use CGI to run a program written in PHP (although mod_php is more common).

Comment: I know what is CGI now. Then what is a CGI program? is it a executable program run in the CGI? And what is the difference between a standalone PHP and traditional CGI programe like perl?

Comment: A CGI program is a program that expects input as per the CGI standard and gives output as per the CGI standard. That's all. "Standalone PHP" would run without interacting with a webserver or web browser at all. Perl is not a CGI program, it is a programming language that (like *any* programming language) can be used via CGI (but [PSGI/Plack](http://plackperl.org/) is the popular choice for new Perl stuff these days).

Answer (score 1):

CGI program is a program that utilize CGI protocol.

Dunno for the servlet but the same PHP code can be run as CGI, FastCGI, php-fpm, apache module, isapi filter and some other ways I believe.